# Custom email directive Angular 7

Tags: angular, email, directive

I am new to angular. I would like to create a form for the user to choose his own email address. I would like to create a directive that allows the user to enter alpha numeric characters, "." or "-", not allowing other characters. Do you have an example please?

Comment: There are built in validators, as well as example regexps that work - mostly. Be aware that the RFCs allow all sorts of things that your stated policy is blocking.  Why not simply make sure all addresses are RFC compliant, and then actually test for validity by sending a confirmation code of some type?

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular's built in EmailValidator https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#email

for Reactive Forms

```
const control = new FormControl('bad@', Validators.email);
```

for Template Drive Forms (

```
<input type="text" name="email" [(ngModel)]="model.property" #email="ngModel" required email />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file email.directive.ts, and use it as provide in main module file. After that use it's selector along with input field. Hope that helps.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[email-directive]'
})

export class EmailDirective {

    private checkPattern(value: string) {
        const regExpString =  "^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.+ ]*$"; // characters only
        return String(value).match(new RegExp(regExpString));
    }

    private specialKeys = [
        'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Delete'
    ];

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private control : NgControl) { }

    lastValue = '';

    @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
    onInput(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
            return;
        }
        let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
        if (current && !this.checkPattern(current)) {
            this.el.nativeElement.value = this.lastValue;
            this.control.control.setValue(this.lastValue);
            return;
        }
        this.lastValue = current;
        this.control.control.setValue(this.lastValue);
    }
}
```